# Javascript: map function appending to an object

Tags: javascript

I have a **map function** which is iterating a response i received from backend. I'm iterating the response as '`tab`' like the code below, what i want to do is to insert '`tab.name`' as an key inside the object `MyObject`

my code:

```
var MyObject = {}
    
response.data.rows.map(tab => {
     MyObject = { 
        ...MyObject,
        tab.name
     }
})
```

What i expect is that my object `MyObject` has every keys and values with the name of tab, e.g:

```
{
   name1: name1,
   name2: name2,
   name3: name3
}
```

The problem is that i can not use `tab.name` inside object

Answer (score 0):

You could use collectjs, goes good..

Anyway if you want to have the keys just do a foreach

```js
let response = [
  {name: 'name1', age: '22'},
  {name: 'name2', age: '25'},
  {name: 'name3', age: '2'},
]

var MyObject = {}

response.forEach(tab => {
     MyObject[tab.name] = tab.name
})

console.log(MyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `.map()`, you could use to create an array of arrays, where each sub-array has a length of 2, and holds the given value at each index.

Then you can use `Object.fromEntries()` to add the properties from that array structure.

```js
var response = {data:{rows:[{name:"foo"}, {name:"bar"}, {name:"baz"}]}};
    
var key_val_props = response.data.rows.map(({name}) => [name, name]);

var MyObject = Object.fromEntries(key_val_props);

console.log(MyObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

Theres no need to copy the object just do

```
MyObject[tab.name] = tab.name;
```

I'd also avoid using `.map` since it will be returning the new reference which I dont think that is what you want.